# Need Drivers for Lexmark S410 Series Printer

Tags: drivers, printing, lexmark

I just got Ubuntu 11.10 on my Sony Laptop and I'm trying to setup a Lexmark S410 Series Printer.

The Disk provided by Lexmark does not open on Ubuntu. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Lexmark website - link to the S415 download follows.  I couldn't find the 410 model, but it looks like it shares the driver with the S415.  I'm also trying to load the driver on a new Ubuntu 12.04.  I haven't completed the entire process yet due to other constraints on my time, and the need to directly cable the Ubuntu machine to a wireless printer that's already configured on the LAN for wireless printing, but I will share what I've accomplished to date.

http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=product&userlocale=RU&locale=ru&productCode=LEXMARK_S415&segment=SUPPORT&nonEFIGSLanguage=en#1

Select the correct version of your operating system (Ubuntu 12.04 is listed on the drop down), whether 32-bit or 64-bit, download the driver utilities, and install on your system.  There are several options available, depending on whether you are using Open Office and need the CUSP Postscript driver, the general utility, or the network scanning utility.   I downloaded all appropriate for 64-bit to have on hand.  I then started with the general utility.

You will then need to physically connect the printer to the Ubuntu machine with a cable the first time as directed by the Lexmark utility.  This is the point at which I had to stop due to other demands on my time.   I will update my response when I've had time to complete the process.